# declaring double use of wildcards in java

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I'm having trouble declaring a fully generic type for the output of a method.
Here's the situation:

```
class A<S,T>{
public Callback<B<S,T>,C<S,T>> method();
}
```

in my code I have one of these;

```
A<String, ?> instance;
```

however, when I call

```
result = instance.method()
```

the only way to make the compiler happy is to declare

```
Callback<?, ?> result = instance.method()
```

But I would really like to be more specific with my generics and declare

```
Callback<B<String, ?>,C<String, ?>> result = instance.method()
```

however, since each wildcard is separate, the compiler complains that this is incorrect, stating that it cannot convert from

```
Callback<B<String,capture#3-of ?>,C<String,capture#3-of ?>>
```

Is there any way of declaring this situation correctly?

FYI, classes A, B, and C are from external libraries.
I tried to declare my instance as

```
A<String, Object>
```

but it's also the result of a method from a fourth class that I have no control over:

```
class D<T>{
public A<T, ?> getObject();
}

D<String> start = new D<String>();
A<String, ?> = start.getObject();
...
```

Comment: The signature of `D.getObject()` gives me a bad feeling. Why would you *return* objects that you can't make any sensible type guarantees over? That is, if `D` doesn't know what type `?` is supposed to be, how the heck should the caller handle this? No wonder the compiler doesn't really try to accomodate you. An `?` should mean "I don't really care what type this is at this point", not "I have no idea what this type should be"

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. I really don't know why this is the case, but it's not my class; it's a core javafx class. Still stuck tho :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed an awkward situation, a result of the limitations of wildcard capture and a less than ideal return type from `D.getObject`.

There are a few workarounds but none are pretty. The first is to simply do an unchecked cast:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //it's okay for the two captures not to match
Callback<B<String, ?>, C<String, ?>> result =
        (Callback<B<String, ?>, C<String, ?>>)instance.method();
```

**EDIT:** Some compilers will (more correctly) require a double cast through `Callback<?, ?>`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //it's okay for the two captures not to match
Callback<B<String, ?>, C<String, ?>> result =
        (Callback<B<String, ?>, C<String, ?>>)(Callback<?, ?>)instance.method();
```

You could also use a helper method - this is a common solution to wildcard capture issues:

```
static <T> void helper(A<String, T> a) {

    Callback<B<String, T>, C<String, T>> result = a.method();

    //logic
}

...

helper(instance);
```

**UPDATE:**

In fact you can combine these two approaches to at least isolate the ugliness into a single helper method:

```
static <S, T> Callback<B<S, ?>, C<S, ?>> disentangleCallback(
        Callback<B<S, T>, C<S, T>> callback
) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //it's okay for the two captures not to match
    final Callback<B<S, ?>, C<S, ?>> withWidenedTypes =
            (Callback<B<S, ?>, C<S, ?>>)(Callback<?, ?>)callback;
    return withWidenedTypes;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Callback<B<String, ?>, C<String, ?>> result =
        disentangleCallback(instance.method());
```

Or else a similar method that simply takes an `A<S, T>` and returns a `Callback<B<S, ?>, C<S, ?>>` by calling `method` itself, then casting.

---

Another idea: if the second type argument of `A` is *always* an unknown, it might be easier to just remove it and widen the return type of `method`:

```
class A<S> {
    public Callback<B<S, ?>, C<S, ?>> method() { ... }
}
```

I realize that would be an unfortunate concession, but it makes sense if `T` is never actually useful.

Comment: solution 1) hard cast is rejected by compiler. solution 2) looking into; has promise. solution 3) I do not have control over class A.

Comment: I see, very nice. It's ugly as sin, but the compiler's happy with the double cast and the call method is compiling. I'll keep you updated on how this ends up working.

Comment: @Jocken Sounds good. See my latest update if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

You could have

```
Callback<? extends B<String, ?>, ? extends C<String, ?>> result
    = instance.method();
```

Comment: I considered this option but it seems like it reduces the usefulness of `result` - depends on how it's used.

Comment: good solution. It's compiling, I'll let you know if it ends up doing what I need it to.

Comment: Problem with the next step: it is now impossible to satisfy the `call(B<String, ?>` method. I have an instance of `B<String, ?>` and I'm now getting this gem from the compiler: The method `call(capture#4-of ? extends B<String,?>) in the type Callback<capture#4-of ? extends B<String,?>,capture#5-of ? extends C<String,?>> is not applicable for the arguments (B<String,capture#8-of ?>`

Comment: @Jocken: But what you are doing is not safe. How do you know that the `?` in the `B<String, ?>` you are passing is the same type as the `?` in the `A<String, ?>` `instance` you had earlier?